# Update Textbox from DataGrid in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, datagrid

I have a silverlight application.I am inserting values in a list and binding that List to datagrid with an edit and delete button before every item in datagrid.

When I click on the edit button, the values present in the item should get displayed in textbox outside datagrid. Now, when I click on edit button, the values get inserted in textbox  at double click of edit button(not on single click) .I am getting the value in the property in code behind in ViewModel but that value is not populated in textbox.It only populates it at second click.

Why so? I want the value to be populated at first click on edit button.

current binding of textbox text property is :

```
Text="{Binding Value,Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: The first click on the edit is probably getting eaten by the datagrid selection changed.  You can test this by adding a selection changed event to your datagrid and see if that gets hit with the first click.

Comment: @RobJacobs Yes , u are right. first click id getting eaten at datagrid selection changed. So what should i do to avoid this.??